# Value passed from one form to another form comes as null value

Tags: c#, winforms

In my windows form application, I am trying to pass one of the value to another form but when the code reach to another form the value shows as null when I use breakpoints.

In Form1 I have one method that generates the OrderNumber and this order number is being used by Form1 itself as well as Form2. If I called Form1.OrderNumber from Form2 it will generate different order number. I want both Forms should have same order number.

So in Form1 I declare global variable as

```
public string ord;
```

Now this "ord" variable gets its value from the following method in Form1.

```
 public string orderNumber()
            {
                string ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
               return ord;
}
```

where the get_next_id is another method which generates number according to the previous number in database.

Now in form1 itself when I use the "ord" variable value in following code the value comes as null.

```
InsertUser(maskedTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, maskedTextBox2.Text, maskedTextBox3.Text, maskedTextBox4.Text, maskedTextBox5.Text,
                       maskedTextBox6.Text, maskedTextBox7.Text, maskedTextBox8.Text, maskedTextBox9.Text, listItems, DateTime.Now, maskedTextBox10.Text, ord, get_next_id());




   }
```

And same happens in form2 as well.

I am not sure where I am wrong.
I posted this question before as well but didn't receive any useful answer.
Any help please..

To pass the value of "ord" to form2 I am calling this code in form 1.

```
                        SaveAllListItems();
                        //this.Close();
                        PrintOrder m = new PrintOrder(ord);
                        m.Show();
```

where PrintOrder is form2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now this "ord" variable gets its value from the following method in
>   Form1.,

Its not, **you are defining a local variable again in the method,** you r not setting the class level variable in your method.

```
public string orderNumber()
{
   string ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
   ^^^^^^^^^^
   //indicating a local variable, not class level
   return ord;
}
```

Should be:

```
public string orderNumber()
{
   ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
   return ord;
}
```

Comment: I did that too but still when I put breakpoint in InserUser code above, the ord is still null..

Comment: @AmritSharma, are you sure you are calling the method `orderNumber`, before the other method, put a break point in `orderNumber` and see if it setting the value

Comment: public string OrderNumber() method doesn't hit by break point at all

Comment: I am just using the value of OrderNumber() method, do I need to call that method..

Comment: @AmritSharma, yes you need to call the method, in order to get the exection, you can specify it in the method `InputUser` parameter as well inplace of `ord`, that will set the value of ord as well plus you will get the value of ord, since thats what the method is returning like": `InsertUser(maskedTextBox1.Text, comboBox1.Text, maskedTextBox2.Text, maskedTextBox3.Text, maskedTextBox4.Text, maskedTextBox5.Text,
                       maskedTextBox6.Text, maskedTextBox7.Text, maskedTextBox8.Text, maskedTextBox9.Text, listItems, DateTime.Now, maskedTextBox10.Text, orderNumber(), get_next_id());`

Answer (score 1):

```
public static string ord;
```

Simple used the static keyword. The Advantage of the Static keyword.

1. Share the memory in whole application.
2. If any user update the value this value get a updated value like that,  One user update the value int x=18 , another user get a value update.
3. static keyword used on compile time binding.

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
string ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
```

use

```
ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because in the following code, you are declaring a new local variable called ord.

```
public string orderNumber()
{
    string ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
    return ord;
}
```

To make it work, change the above function to:

```
public void OrderNumber()
{
    ord = "ORD" + DateTime.Now.Year + get_next_id();
}
```

`OrderNumber` does not need to return a value since you will be using `ord` anyways.

`OrderNumber` needs to be called before you try to retrieve the value for `ord`. When you initially declare `ord`, the value is null. Calling `OrderNumber` will change it's value from null to whatever you like.

Comment: Still the ord is null if I follow you solution, when I put breakpoint in Insertuser..

Comment: You need to make sure that `OrderNumber` is called before you try to use `ord`.

Comment: But where do I need to call the ordernumber method

Comment: That depends on when you can call the `get_next_id()` method.